# Variables in URL, where does it apply when the 1st one redirect to another page?

Tags: php, url

I have the following URL: `http://some_URL/file/?var1=../dir/page.php&var2=value2`

Let's say that **var1** is used to redirect to another page (`page.php` here), does the value of **var2** will be applied to the current page (before I press ENTER), or will it be applied to `page.php` ?

Comment: This URL structure make no sense.

Comment: maybe this might help? https://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/

Comment: @Twinfriends — It's a perfectly valid URL.

Comment: @Quentin Yes you're right. Haven't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking will the parameters on the query string automatically be passed on from the first script to a script that the first script redirects to.

The answer is no, not automatically.

The querystring will be passed to the first script and that script will receive both parameters in the $_GET array.

First script

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
```

Now if you want to redirect to a script identified in the `var1` parameter  and pass `var2` on to that script you have to add it to the redirect call, like this

```
header("Location: $var1?var2=$var2");
```

So if `var1` is `../dir/page.php` and `var2` is `value2` this will expand to

```
header("Location: ../dir/page.php?var2=value2");
```

Alternatively, if the first script is itself a visible page with a form in it you can make the parameter pass on to the next script using a hidden input

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
?>

<form action="<?php echo $var1;?> ........>
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="<?php echo $var2;?>">
```

> Of course its dangerous using unvalidated querystring parameters so anything in the `$_GET` array needs to be sanity checked before using it in anything

Answer (score 0):

The `&` character delimits key=value pairs. Everything after the first `&` will not be part of the value for `var=1`.

Use [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to include special characters as data in a URL.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I'm only asking if we have this URL in a well coded website (this is not my website), var2 is a variable for the current page (before I press ENTER) or for page.php  ?

Answer (score 0):

As such, `var2` will be available in the current page. To make it available in page.php, get the `var2` variable and append it to the new url before redirecting.